# Validar que solo contenga una mayúscula

Tags: javascript, regex

Este código muestra su alerta cuando no tengo una minúscula o mayúscula o número, o mide menos de 7.

Querría saber cómo hacer para que **solo acepte una mayúscula** (no al menos una).

```
else if (!/[a-z]/.test(contraseña) || !/[A-Z]/.test(contraseña) || !/[0-9]/.test(contraseña) || contraseña.length < 7) {
    alert("El campo 'Contraseña' no es correcto. Es obligatorio, de mínimo 7 caracteres, y debe contener una mayúscula, una minúscula y un dígito");
}
```

Comment: y qué has intentado para lograrlo ?

Comment: !/[A-Z]{1}/.test(contraseña)
{} seria que solo se repite una vez no? No me va

Comment: Si te interesa una respuesta más corta, te he respondido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A parte de comprobar que exista una mayúscula debes comprobar que ni antes ni después haya ninguna:

```
/^[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/
```

De esta forma compruebas la cadena desde el principio (`^`) hasta el final (`$`).

Que exista una mayúscula: `[A-Z]`

Y que antes o después puedan existir de 0 a n (`*`) caracteres que no sean mayúsculas (`[^A-Z]`): `[^A-Z]*`

```js
document.getElementById('validar').addEventListener('click',
  function(){
    var contraseña = document.getElementById('password').value;
    console.log('Tiene alguna minúscula',
      /[a-z]/.test(contraseña));
    console.log('Tiene alguna mayúscula',
      /[A-Z]/.test(contraseña));
    console.log('Tiene algún dígito',
      /[0-9]/.test(contraseña));
    console.log('Tiene una sóla mayúscula',
      /^[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/.test(contraseña));    
  }
);
```

```html
<input id="password" type="text">
<button id="validar">Validar</button>
```

Comment: No hay forma de hacerlo mas sencillo como a continuacion, no valdria? Pense que {1} es que haya SOLO UNA=>

 
!/[A-Z]{1}/.test(contraseña)

Comment: Así compruebas que exista una única mayúscula consecutiva, no compruebas lo anterior o posterior. Utilizar el cuantificador `{}` con un `1` es como no usarlo, es decir `/[A-Z]{1}/` es lo mismo que `/[A-Z]/`

Comment: @franciscodwq ¡¿Más sencillo que `/^[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/.test(contraseña)`?! Es 1 línea. ¿Cuánto más se podría simplificar, o para qué?

Answer (score 1):

**En una función pequeña:**

```
 var lock = (e, max, arr = e.value.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []) => arr.length === max;
```

**Y lo usas, como:**

```js
var lock = (e, max, arr = e.value.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []) => arr.length === max;
       

document.getElementById("gt").onclick = () => { 
  if(lock(document.getElementById("mayus"), 1)) console.log("Correcto");
  else console.log("Se requiere exactamente 1 mayuscula");
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mayus">
<input type="button" id=gt value="Enviar">
```

Comment: Aunque la respuesta ya está aceptada, lo he corregido, gracias